# Calling PHP Class

Tags: php, class, call

Is there any way to call a php class (eg. $var = new className) and have var store the value returned by the className function?

Or, is there a way to call a class and not have it execute the function with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function of the same name as the class was they way 'constructors' in php 4 worked.
This function is called automatically when a new object instance is created.

In php 5, a new magic function __construct() is used instead.
If your using php5 and don't include a '__construct' method, php will search for an old-style constructor method.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

So if you are using php5, add a '__construct' method to your class, and php will quit executing your 'method of the same name as the class' when a new object is constructed.

Comment: Omg thank you sooooo much. Adding a blank __construct method is exactly what I needed to make this work. Your amazing!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible in PHP5 using magical method __toString(); to return a value from the class instance/object.

simply

```
class MyClass{

function __construct(){
  // constructor
}

function __toString(){
  // to String
  return 5;
}

}

$inst = new MyClass();

echo $inst; // echos 5
```

Constructors don't return value (in fact you can't do that). If you want to get a value from the instance of the class, use the __toString() magical method.

Comment: So I would have to rename the function to __toString?

Comment: constructors don't return value. If you want to get a value from the instance of the class, use the __toString() magical method

Answer (score 0):

Constructors don't return values, they are used to instantiate the new object you are creating.  $var will always contain a reference to the new object using the code you provided.

To be honest, from your question, it sounds like you don't understand the intention of classes.

Comment: I'm not very good at explaining what I mean. Right now I am calling the constructor just like a normal function and it would return data. But the issue is that the function then gets called twice, once when for the class, and once when i reference it. Is there any way to get around this without changing the name? I know another way I can do it, but i didn't really want to change it.

Comment: I'm afraid its on multiple different pages, and not very easy to post here. I'll just go with my other idea. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`$var = new classname` will always return an instance of `classname`. You can't have it return something else.

Read this...
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php